# Sitecore E-commerce Fundamental Edition

Tags: e-commerce, sitecore

I have installed the Sitecore E-commerce Fundamental Edition (Sitecore_E-Commerce_FE_1.1.0_rev._110511)and The examples (Sitecore_E-Commerce_FE_Examples_1.1.0_rev._110511) packages. If I add a new product to the product  repository it is listet at the Product Search Group(Product Page) in the content tree. So far no problems. But when I try to create a new template based on the product template this doesn't work. If I copy or dublicate a already existing produckt temple (for example SLR) content created by this template doesn't work. It's like only the example productstemple are accepted for the Product Seach Group. I have tried to find if the product template  have to be accepted by the Product Search Group but with no success. What am I missing?

Regards Karl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!

You have to add the new product template in /sitecore/system/Modules/Ecommerce/Catalogs/Product Catalog